# Is it possible to stay in Face Mode when making loop cuts?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

It appears that *Loop Cut* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) automatically switches you to Edge Mode.

Is there a way to remain in Face Mode after doing a Loop Cut? I've looked through the hot key references that I could find but no luck.

Comment: AFAIK, no. I think the best you could do is write a python script to perform the loopcut, then switch back to facemode when Ctrl+R is pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can in a way.. In the 3d view header, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the *Edge* and *Face* icons. [image] The only drawback to this is that you will be in both *Edge* and *Face* selection mode.

Also, the quickest way to switch selection modes in Blender is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, *(you can also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting here too to get multiple selection modes, to leave a mode, do the same thing)*.

Comment: Having BOTH the Edge and Face modes active at the same time did the trick.  I'm finding that particular workflow far simpler now.  Thanks for the tip